# ASP.net failing to add role to user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm able to create a new user but fail to add a role to the created user
Here my cs code :

#### to generate role into the dropdownlist

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateUserWizard CreateUserWizard1 = (CreateUserWizard)LoginView1.FindControl("CreateUserWizard1");

            DropDownList role = (DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("role");
            if(role!=null)
            {
                string[] allRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
                foreach (string roles in allRoles)
                {
                    role.Items.Add(new ListItem(roles));  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### to insert role into username

```
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateUserWizard CreateUserWizard1 = (CreateUserWizard)LoginView1.FindControl("CreateUserWizard1");
        DropDownList role = (DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("role");
        Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, role.SelectedValue);
    }
```

ASPX Code:

#### createuserwizard in loginview

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <RoleGroups>
            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="System Admin">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" 
                        BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
                    ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx">
                        <SideBarStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" BorderWidth="0px" Font-Size="0.9em" 
                            VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <SideBarButtonStyle BorderWidth="0px" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="White" />
                        <ContinueButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                            ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                            ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
                            Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <CreateUserButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                            ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <StepStyle BorderWidth="0px" />
                        <WizardSteps>
                            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table border="0" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:100%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2" 
                                                style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;">
                                                Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User 
                                                Name:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                                    AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                                    ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." 
                                                    ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Role :"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="role" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >

                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security 
                                Question:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security 
                                Answer:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                                    Display="Dynamic" 
                                                    ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
                                                    ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                            <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" >
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table border="0" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:100%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2" 
                                                style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;">
                                                Complete</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Your account has been successfully created.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                <asp:Button ID="ContinueButton" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBFF" 
                                                    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Continue" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                                                    ForeColor="#284775" Text="Continue" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                        </WizardSteps>
                    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
                    </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:RoleGroup>
        </RoleGroups>
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            Access Denied.
        </AnonymousTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
```

Can anyone help me to find and fix my error?

Comment: Drop `CreateUserWizard` into `AnonymousTemplate` set `oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser"`

Comment: Do you "add role to user" or "add user to role" ? It might be a stupid question but I've never had to work with role creation before and your code looks like "add user to role" when you say "add role to user"... Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks @AVD ^^ ....it work after i added oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ^^ after I added

```
oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser"
```

inside CreateUserWizard tag